# Nav bar text not showing

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5, nav

I am very new to all this. I am building a simple nav bar, but no text/links are showing up on it. How do I get the links to show up? All that is showing up is the logo img and the hamburger icon. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <!--Bootstrap CDN  -->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
   integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <!-- Custom CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- nav bar -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="the-larder-logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Food <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Drink</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Special Events</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
     <!-- end of nav bar -->
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If we check with Chrome dev tool,we can find below:
[image]

`display:none` made it invisible,so if we want to see navbar,we need to change

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
```

to

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
```

Note:
This is just solve the problem to make navbar visible,since I am not very good at `Bootstrap`,I think there are more elegant way to solve it

---

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <!--Bootstrap CDN  -->
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <!-- Custom CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

     <!-- nav bar -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="the-larder-logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Change</span>
      </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Food <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Drink</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Special Events</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
         <!-- end of nav bar -->
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: This aligns the words down the page, instead of across the page. Is there anyway to align then across the page?

Answer (score 0):

- Your toggler button `navbar-toggler` is pointing to a different target(`navbarSupportedContent`) than the  menu you have in your code `navbarNavAltMarkup`, the `id` you specify for the element `collapse navbar-collapse` needs to be use as value in `data-bs-target`
- Your html it's pointing to [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/) and you have code from Bootstrap 4.

You need to update these 2, on Bootstrap 5 changed and it includes `-bs-` now, in previous versions it was as you currently have it

- `data-toggle` -> `data-bs-toggle`
- `data-target` -> `data-bs-target`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="the-larder-logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Food <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Drink</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Special Events</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```